# Fill Subdivisions of Chloropeth Map with multiple Colors

Tags: r, plot, r-sf, geopackage

I want to create a plot of Germany, where each of its 16 Bundesländer (Subdivisons) is colored differently, depending on the fulfillment of a handful of criteria. At the bottom you find a representative sketch. The idea is, that you see right away which subdivision meets which criteria.

Each criterium stands for a different color, these are

```
library(RColorBrewer)
Colors <- brewer.pal(5, "Spectral") 
Colors
[1] "#D7191C" "#FDAE61" "#FFFFBF" "#ABDDA4" "#2B83BA"
```

Now, I have a list of 16, which contains the color(s) of each Bundesland, depending on which criteria they meet. For example:

```
Berlin
[1] "#D7191C" "#FDAE61" "#FFFFBF" "#ABDDA4" 
Bavaria
[1] "#D7191C" "#FDAE61"
Hamburg
[1] "#ABDDA4"
```

As you can see, they all differ in length.

Now, I was wondering, how I could pass these multiple color information to my chloropleth map? I have downloaded the Geopackage for Germany from [GADM](https://www.gadm.org/download_country.html).

The following gives a plain plot of the map, where you can only see the borders of the Bundesländer (attached)

```
library(sf)
library(cartography)
plot(st_geometry(Germany), col = NA, border = "white", bg = "#aadaff")
```

Passing my list of colors as

```
"col = Colors"
```

Is, of course, not working, and does not fill the subdivisions with the desired color(s).

[image: Desired Map]

Comment: Please consider {tmap} package for maping: https://r-tmap.github.io/tmap/

Comment: A good data visualization practice is to typically limit choropleths to displaying only a single color at a time. So you could either create small multiples (e.g., five different iterations of the same map, one for each color scheme, showing whether a Bundesländer meets or does not meet the specific criterion represented by that color) or instead have your color scale represent how *many* criteria are met (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and all 5). Filling *each* Bundesländer with up to 5 different colors will quickly become too chaotic to look at.

Comment: Dear Cristian and Grzegorz, thank you very much for your helpful comments. Both are alternatives that I will consider. At the moment, the messy version is prioritized by my chef ...

Comment: I would also like to jump on this train. Just because you could, does not mean you should (but this discussion must be held elsewhere...). Filling rather small polygons like Berlin with up to 4 different colors will be a mess and not very helpful in getting your message across. However, since you would not want to alter the geometry of your object, you might be interested in hatchings? Maybe using `{ggpattern}`?

Comment: Dear dimfalk, thank you very much for this great suggestion. Could you maybe just help me regarding the 'geom_polygon_pattern' function? My idea (see below) would be to pass the arrays 'pats', 'fills' and 'patfills' (all length 16), where each entry represents a Bundesland. However, aesthetics must be length 1 ... 

    Germany <- getData(country = "Germany", level = 1);
    ggplot(Germany,     aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + geom_polygon_pattern( pattern = pats, fill = fills, pattern_fill = patfills, color = 'black' )

Comment: @Frosi, are you saying, that each Bundesland can be subdivided up to 4 colors (criteria)? If that's the goal, I would spatially divide each Bundesland to number of required criteria and then apply a color. The division can be quite easy intersection of Bundesland and it's bounding box divided by number of criteria. Or rotated by 45 deg. Not sure how otherwise map up to 4 different colors to one Bundesland.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update:

OP states that they need multiple colors per Bundesländer. Assuming they have a named list or a dataframe with the colors, they can join it with their shapefile. Here, I am creating a set of random colors. I assign the colors to each state (assigning multiple colors to some of them).

Then I would [divide each state that has multiple colors to equal parts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/440698/93948).

Finally, I plot the divided up polygons (without a border) and would plot the original polygons with no color but only a white border (here I chose black to show them more clearly) on top of it to show the original subdivisions/state borders. I am not sure why the background color does not work.

<sub>I feel there should be a better approach here, hence, a bounty.</sub>

```r
#### libraries ####

library(sf)
library(sp)
library(dismo)
library(deldir)
library(dplyr)
```

```
#### downloading the data ####

download.file("https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/gadm/gadm4.1/shp/gadm41_DEU_shp.zip",
              "gadm41_DEU_shp.zip")
unzip("gadm41_DEU_shp.zip", exdir= "DEU_adm")

Germany <- st_read(dsn="DEU_adm\\gadm41_DEU_1.shp", quiet = TRUE)
```

```
#### pre-processing the data and defining the split funciton ####

## creating a set of random colors, you should use your desired colors
set.seed(123)
cp <- sample(grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y|white',
             grDevices::colors(), invert = T)], 24)

Germany$COLORS <- I(list(cp[1], cp[2:3], cp[3:5], cp[6:9], 
                         cp[10], cp[11], cp[12], cp[13],
                         cp[14], cp[15], cp[16], cp[17],
                         cp[18], cp[19], cp[20], cp[21:24]))

wgs84 <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

## taken from https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/440698/93948
## split polygons 
split_poly <- function(sf_poly, n_areas) {
  # Create random points
  points_rnd <- st_sample(sf_poly, size = 10000)
  # k-means clustering
  points <- do.call(rbind, st_geometry(points_rnd)) %>%
    as_tibble() %>% setNames(c("lon","lat"))
  k_means <- kmeans(points, centers = n_areas)
  # Create voronoi polygons
  voronoi_polys <- dismo::voronoi(k_means$centers, ext = sf_poly)
  # Clip to sf_poly
  crs(voronoi_polys) <- wgs84 ## hardcoding crs
  voronoi_sf <- st_as_sf(voronoi_polys)
  equal_areas <- st_intersection(voronoi_sf, sf_poly)
  #equal_areas$area <- st_area(equal_areas)
  return(equal_areas)
}
```

```
#### splitting the polygons and plotting ####

## split polygons for each Bundesländer based on number of colors provided
pol_areas  <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(Germany)), function(i) 
        if (length(unlist(Germany[i,]$COLORS)) == 1) {Germany[i,]} 
        else {split_poly(Germany[i,], length(unlist(Germany[i,]$COLORS)))}) 

## combine the splited polygons to one sf object
bind_rows(pol_areas) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Color = ifelse(is.na(id), COLORS, COLORS[id])) -> mapdata_deu 

## plot
plot(mapdata_deu[,"geometry"],
     col = mapdata_deu$Color, 
     bg = "#aadaff", border = NA)
plot(Germany[,"geometry"],
     col = NA, 
     bg = NA, border = "black", add = T)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-04-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

---

---

I am not quite sure what are the colors that you want for each state (i.e. Bundesland), but the code below does the job. You can change the `Colors` variable as desired.

```r
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

Germany <- getData(country = "Germany", level = 1) 

Colors <- c("#D7191C", "#FDAE61", "#FFFFBF", "#ABDDA4",
            "#D7191C", "#FDAE61", "#ABDDA4", "#D7191C", 
            "#FDAE61", "#FFFFBF", "#ABDDA4", "#2B83BA",
            "#D7191C", "#FDAE61", "#ABDDA4", "#D7191C")

plot(Germany, 
     col = Colors[as.numeric(as.factor(Germany$NAME_1))], 
     border = "white", bg = "#aadaff")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Dear M, thank you very much for your answer. This is not exactly what I am looking for. I will update my post in the next minutes with a sketch